# Objective C Inheritence

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, core-data

I am trying to subclass some Core Data classes. I've got the following classes:

Core Data class:

```
@interface CDExplanatoryMaterial : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * document;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pageNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * realPageNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;

@end
```

Business logic class's protocol:

```
@protocol BLDataClass <NSObject>

- (NSArray*)favouriteInGroups;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString* type;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSArray* inFavouriteGroups;

- (void)addAddToFavouriteGroup: (NSString*) groupName;
- (void)removeFromFavouriteGroup: (NSString*) groupName;
- (void)addToHistory;

@end
```

Interface for BLExplanatoryMaterial:

```
@interface BLExplanatoryMaterial : CDExplanatoryMaterial <BLDataClass>
```

I get the data like this:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*) explanatoryMaterials {
    NSMutableArray* results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(CDExplanatoryMaterial *item in [Helper fetchDataObjectsOfType:@"CDExplanatoryMaterial"])
    {
        [results addObject: (BLExplanatoryMaterial*)item];
    }
    return results;
}
```

The helper class looks like this:

```
@implementation Helper
+ (NSArray*) fetchDataObjectsOfType:(NSString *)type {
    DataManager* manager = [DataManager sharedInstance];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:type inManagedObjectContext:manager.mainObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [manager.mainObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return fetchedObjects;
}
@end
```

This issue that I have is that the fetchedObjects array in fetchDataObjectsOfType and the results array in explanatoryMaterials only contain NSManagedObject objects. I'd expect fetchedObjects to contain CDExplanatoryMaterial objects and results to contain BLExplanatoryMaterial. I need the end result to be BLExplanatoryMaterial objects or I can't use any of my instance methods, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Joe

EDIT:

Just to clarify it is the following code that fails because expMat is an NSManagedObject and doesn't support the addToFavouriteGroup method.

```
NSMutableArray* expMats = [Data explanatoryMaterials];
BLExplanatoryMaterial* expMat = (BLExplanatoryMaterial*) [expMats objectAtIndex:0];
[((BLExplanatoryMaterial*)expMat) addToFavouriteGroup:@"Test Group"]
```

One thing that I forgot to mention is that all of the code in my original post is in a static library. The code posted in this edit is in a IOS App project. I'm not sure if this makes a difference. All of the classes in the static library are marked as public.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `BLExplanatoryMaterial` as the class for the entity in your managed object model. This will tell Core Data to instantiate objects of that class instead of `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: I've just looked in the Configurations -> Default bit and it says that CDExplanatoryMaterial is the class for the CDExplanatoryMaterial entity. This looks correct I think? I'll try changing it.

Comment: Changing the class makes no difference.

Comment: Can you override `-awakeFromFetch` in your `NSManagedObject` subclass, to see if it gets called when an object is fetched from the store?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help. It turns out that because the core data classes were in a seperate static library they were not being built in to the main bundle. To get around this I subclassed them within my main application and then pointed the core data file at those subclasses.